# Handling the return of the queue:out_r

Tags: erlang

I have a statement where I want to remove the last item in a queue using out_r.

The Docs say that the return is

> Result = {{value, Item}, Q2} | {empty, Q1}
>       Q1 = Q2 = queue()

How do I handle this if I just want to get the queue with the item removed?

How do I get the queue and disregard the {value, item}?

e.g.
`NewQueue = queue:out_r(OldQueue)`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pattern matching!

```
{_, NewQueue} = queue:out_r(OldQueue)
```

Given both `{value, Item}` and `empty` are returned as the first element of the tuple, ignoring the first element will do what you want.

Note that the queue module supports 3 APIs. Other APIs might do what you want better. In this case, you can have the same function, except it crashes if the queue is empty:

```
drop_r(Q1) -> Q2
Returns a queue Q2 that is the result of removing the rear item from Q1.
Fails with reason empty if Q1 is empty.
```

Picking one or the other depends on your applications and what you expect to be in the queue, if you can handle an empty one, etc.

Comment: the queue will be empty at the start. I just want to remove the item.(I will only remove an item if it has a length of N(always larger than 0)) I want to remove the item and continue with that queue.

Comment: Pick whichever of the two options above then. If you are sure that the queue will never be empty when you try to remove the last element, I'd personally go with `drop_r/1` so if anything weird goes wrong with your code, that's where it'll crash, as early as possible. So `NewQueue = queue:drop_r(OldQueue)`.